# Uninstall application which prompts using VB Script

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, uninstallation

I have an application which was deployed some time ago using an .msi and a .mst

When I now try to uninstall the app using **msiexec /x name_of_msi TRANSFORMS=name_of_mst /qb!** I get a prompt asking if I would like to remove the ini files which were installed.  Is there any way to uninstall the application and answer "Yes" to the prompt using a vbscript.

Thanks

G

Comment: `/qb!` means basic UI with no Cancel button. Does it help if you use `/q` or `/qn` (no UI) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried employing the /passive or /quiet switch?

/quiet - quiet mode (no user interaction)
/passive - unattended mode (progress bar only)

/q - set the UI level:

- n - no UI
- b - basic UI
- r - reduced UI
- f - full UI

Try:
msiexec /x name_of_msi TRANSFORMS=name_of_mst /qn /quiet
**or**
msiexec /x name_of_msi TRANSFORMS=name_of_mst /qn /passive